# Getting error while running update query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am new to PostgreSQL. While running below update query I am getting below error.

```
update useremails ue 
SET ue.useinstitutionid=id.InstitutionID from instdomains id 
where ue.email REGEXP CONCAT('^.*[.@]',id.DomainMask,'$');
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REGEXP"

**Mysql query**

```
UPDATE useremails
JOIN instdomains ON useremails.email 
REGEXP CONCAT('^.*[.@]',instdomains.DomainMask,'$')
SET useremails.useinstitutionid=instdomains.InstitutionID;
```

I converted this query from mysql to Postgresql. How can rewrite this query in postgresql?

Comment: Where [in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html) did you find the `regexp` operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex operator in Postgres is `~`, not `REGEXP` (which is used by MySQL and SQLite).  Try this version:

```sql
UPDATE useremails ue
SET useinstitutionid = id.InstitutionID
FROM instdomains id
WHERE ue.email ~* ('^.*[.@]' || id.DomainMask);  -- case insensitive, for a case
                                                 -- sensitive match just use ~
```

Note that you could almost as easily phrase the above update using the regular `LIKE` operator:

```sql
UPDATE useremails ue
SET useinstitutionid = id.InstitutionID
FROM instdomains id
WHERE ue.email LIKE '%.' || id.DomainMask || '%' OR
      ue.email LIKE '%@' || id.DomainMask || '%';
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. I have one small doubt that ,In your first query you used ~ symbol,is it case sensitive?

Comment: If you read the comments there, you'll see that I mention that `~*` is case insensitive.  The case sensitive regex like is just tilde `~` by itself.

Comment: getting this error ERROR:  `argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text` . email should be text only ,I cannot convert to boolean

Comment: That's not what the error message is referring to.  It is claiming that the expression in your `WHERE` clause is evaluating to text rather than boolean.  That should not be the case with either of my answers, leading me to believe that you are not really running my code.

Comment: I am running your code  `db_replica=> UPDATE useremails ue SET ue.useinstitutionid = id.Institution_ID FROM instdomains id WHERE ue.email ~* '^.*[.@]' || id.Domain_Mask;`
**ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 1: ...nid = id.Institution_ID FROM instdomains id WHERE ue.email ~...**

Comment: ` and In your second query I am getting error as `db_replica=> UPDATE useremails ue SET ue.useinstitutionid = id.Institution_ID FROM instdomains id WHERE ue.email LIKE '%.' || id.Domain_Mask || '%' OR ue.email LIKE '%@' || id.Domain_Mask || '%';`
**ERROR:  column "ue" of relation "useremails" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE useremails ue SET ue.useinstitutionid = id.Institutio...**

Comment: @Moolya: `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL, not an "or" if you thought it would do that. Please see Tim's answer for the correct usage of multiple LIKE conditions combined with OR that concatenate strings

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried both queryies but   I am getting above error which I updated earlier in comment

Comment: You need to remove the `ue.` prefix from the left hand side in the `SET` assignment

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok thanks, let me try